# Replacing accented/umlauted characters with their unadorned counterparts in C#

Tags: c#, string, diacritics

### Duplicate of [249087](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net)

I have a bunch of user generated addresses that may contain characters with diacritic marks. 
What is the most effective (i.e. generic) way (apart from a straightforward replace) to automatically convert any such characters to their closest English equivalent?

E.g. 
any of **àâãäå** would become **a**

**æ** would become the two separate letters **ae**

**ç** would become **c**

any of **èéêë** would become **e**

etc. for all possible letter variations (preferably without having to find and encode lookups for each diacritic form of the letter).

(Note: I have to pass these addresses on to third party software that is incapable of printing anything other than English characters. I'd rather the software was capable of handling them, but I have no control over that.)

EDIT: Never mind... Found the answer [here][2]. It showed up in the "Related" section to the right of the question after I posted, but **not** in my prior search or as a pre-post suggestion. Hmm. I added the 'diacritics' tag to the other question in any case.

EDIT 2: Jeez! Who voted this -1 after I closed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just was going to post the same link :-)

Sounds like you're doing this already, but I would recommend that you store the original string for display in your application, and only do this for the 3rd-party stuff. People get cranky if they don't think their real name is important :-)

Comment: Ah, well that's not gonna be possible....
The software I pass the addresses to prints mailing labels :)